# Trying to map through an array, but getting a typeerror message saying that *Array*.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

As part of my  React learning, I am trying to make an HTTP request using XMLHttpRequest in React. I am trying to pull data from a [jokesApi](https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2#getting-started) and then display it in the render. However, I am getting the following error message:
***TypeError: this.state.jokes.map is not a function***

Can somebody guide as to why I am getting this error? When I console.log, the jokes were appearing in the console box. I figured since I was storing the jokes in an array the best way to render it was by mapping through it.

```
import React from 'react';

 class DadJokesApi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            error: null,
            jokes: []
        }
    }
 componentDidMount() 
 { 
     this.getData() 
}

 getData() { 
     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() 
     xhr.addEventListener('load', () => { 
         if(xhr.readyState === 4){
             if(xhr.status === 200){
                 var response = xhr.responseText,
                 json = JSON.parse(response);

                 this.setState({
                     isLoaded: true,
                     jokes:json
                 });
             } else {
                 this.setState({
                     isLoaded: true,
                     error: xhr.responseText
                 })
             }
         }
      }) 
     xhr.open('GET', ' https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/any', true) 
     xhr.send();
    }
 render() { 
    var body;
    if(!this.state.isLoaded){
        body = <div>...Loading</div>;
    } else if (this.state.error) {
        body = <div>Error occurred { this.state.error} </div>
    } else {
        var jokes = this.state.jokes.map(
            joke => <div key={joke.id} className="jokesdisplay">{jokes.en}</div>
        );
        body = <div>{jokes}</div> 
    }
return body;
 }
}
export default DadJokesApi;
```

Comment: https://sv443.net/jokeapi/v2/joke/any does not return an array, so `jokes` is not an array

Comment: Jokes is the JSON result parsed to an object. It's not an array.

Comment: @JMadelaine so I am guessing I would need to use JSON.parse then?

Comment: @CertainPerformance looks like I may need to use JSON.parse then?

Comment: You've already used JSON.parse: `json = JSON.parse(response)`. Console.log the value of `jokes` and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I figured since I was storing the jokes in an array the best way to render it was by mapping through it.

You're not storing the jokes in an array - you initialize the `jokes` state value to an array `[]`, but then every time you fetch a new joke, you're overwriting the `jokes` state value with just that joke, which is an object:

```
/*
 *  The value of json is the parsed response data, e.g.:
 *  {
 *    category: "Programming",
 *    type: "single",
 *    joke: "ASCII silly question, get a silly ANSI.",
 *    flags: {
 *      nsfw: false,
 *      religious: false,
 *      political: false,
 *      racist: false,
 *      sexist: false
 *    },
 *    id: 25,
 *    error: false
 *  }
 */
json = JSON.parse(response);

this.setState({
  isLoaded: true,
  // You set jokes to json, which is not an array, it's a single joke object
  jokes: json
})
```

Now that `jokes` is just a single joke object, you get the error `this.state.jokes.map is not a function` because `object.map` is not a function.

To fix this, just add the fetched joke to the state array instead of overwriting it:

```
this.setState(prev => ({
  isLoaded: true,
  // Spread the previous jokes array and append the new joke json
  jokes: [...prev.jokes, json]
}))
```